# Android Textview spitting out something I never wrote

Tags: android

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Why did it say hello world?");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I'm following the Hello, World tutorial on the android SDK site. When I set the text for tv, it never shows. Instead, the output is:

Hello World, HelloAndroid!

Where in the world is that coming from? I never wrote that text, ever, anywhere...freaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);             << create TextView object
tv.setText("Why did it say hello world?");    << set text to it
setContentView(R.layout.main);                << display the view defined in main.xml
```

as **scriptocalypse** said you can simply set the content view to **tv**, alternatively, and I think a better approach is to use the `main.xml`:

in `main.xml` there is a `TextView` and it has a property called `id`, it looks something like this: `<TextView android:id="@+id/text"` you can use this id to get the TextView object of this xml like this:

```
setContentView(R.id.xml);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText("Your text");
```

There are 3 things to remember:

1. `R.id.text` is corresponding to `android:id="@+id/text"`.
2. `R.id.text` is an integer, generated during the build of application, it's not a string, and cannot be manipulated as a string.
3. `setContentView` has to be called before calling `findViewById`, otherwise, you will get null as return value of `findViewById`.

Comment: Since you gave a more in-depth description and solution, I think it's best if this answer is marked as the correct one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check your `main.xml` file.  It's likely being printed from there.

To get your own test there, add your new `TextView` to the `main.xml`

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Your text here" />
```

(Note: the "Your text here" should really be brought out to the `strings.xml` file.)

To put in an editable text field, use an `EditText` field.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/TextId" android:hint="background text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setContentView before creating a new TextView object.  Also, did you remember to add the TextView to the display?

```
 setContentView(tv)
```

I see you adding the xml layout, but you never add the newly created TextView

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setContentView() and passing in a reference to a layout, specifically main.xml as noted by Haphazard.  If you want to see your TextView that you just created, you should be able to pass the variable tv into the setContentView() method.

The default main.xml has a reference to a String in strings.xml in your res/ folder.  In there is the definition of a String "Hello World", which is why you are seeing "Hello World".